# Why different variable scope between parameter and input dataset variables?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017

When using [sp_execute_external_script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql) to execute Python from SQL Server 2017, SQL parameters passed into the script become global variables in Python while the input data set becomes a local variable.

Why the difference in scope? Why don't both become local variables or both become global variables?

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'python', 
@script = N'
print("Is InputDataSet global? " + str("InputDataSet" in globals()))
print("Is InputDataSet local? " + str("InputDataSet" in locals()))
print("Is i (passed in parameter) global? " + str("i" in globals()))
print("Is i (passed in parameter) local? " + str("i" in locals()))
',
@input_data_1 = N'select 1',
@params = N'@i INT',
@i = 10;
```

Produces:

```
Is InputDataSet global? False
Is InputDataSet local? True
Is i (passed in parameter) global? True
Is i (passed in parameter) local? False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy in variable scope may seem strange when viewed from the context of `@script` being invoked one time to process the entire input result set at once.

However, `sp_execute_external_script` can also be used to stream results to `@script` for it to process one chunk at a time. In this context, the difference in scope makes sense:

- Each input data set is only relevant to the current invocation of `@script` so is put into a local variable.
- Parameters should stay around for the lifespan of the script process so are declared as globals (i.e. they should be set once and then remain in memory until all chunks have been processed and the final result set returned).

### Background

Behind the scenes, the context of `@script` is injected into a script template before it is executed. From what I can tell, the code in `@script` become part of method that's called once for each result set chunk that needs processing. Each time the method is called, a local variable is populated with the current chunk of the input result set before the code in `@script` is executed.